# Use .lib to compile then use .dll to link or explicitly call dll in C++?

Tags: c++, c, dll

Trying to write a VS2015 .dll project to learn about .lib and .dll but was confused by explicit use and implicit use dll.

Right now I create a .dll project and successfully complied it, then I get a test.lib and test.dll, so with my test.h it should be good to use in another project to verify the functionality right?

Here's my steps:

1. create a win32 application project containing a .c file called "example.c", which include "test.h". And I put my "test.lib" into the same directory of this project.
2. compile the project and get a release version.
3. put "test.dll" into release directory
4. double click .exe and everything is good.

My problem is one of my college said my procedure was just using the static library and no dynamic library involved, and I should explicitly load "test.dll", which makes me so confused, since I thought .lib will not containing the actual code, it should only been used during compile time.

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: `.lib` file can be two kinds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your college is wrong.

Your library project have created an import library(.lib) and the dll, when you link to your .lib, it is just a stub pointing to the dll file. If you remove the .dll file from where your .exe file sits, the .exe file should not start, so that's one way to verify that you need the .dll.

A .lib file in Windows can be either a static library or an import library.

**Static Library**

If it is a static library, all the code is contained in the .lib file and when you link to that .lib file the code is embedded in your executable. No dll file is used/needed.

**Import Library**

If the .lib file is an import library, it just contains a stub that points to the .dll, when you link to this, your executable does not embed the code of the library, it is linked to the .dll. The executable requires the .dll to be present, and will try to load it automatically when the exe starts.

**Dynamic loaded**

The third option is to have your code load the .dll explicitly, and extract/cast all functions/etc. from the dll using a string representation of its name. With this method you don't link to any .lib file during build time - this method is useful if you want to load plugins or dlls, but still have your executable work if those dlls are not present. This is likely what your college is talking about, and you probably don't need to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think he maybe misunderstanding my .lib file as static library.

Comment: if it helped you maybe you can accept the answer then